# C & CXX compiler identification is unknown

Tags: ubuntu, installation, avogadro

I am a new user of Linux and trying to download Avogadro 1.2.0.
I'm having trouble using the command `cmake ../`, when I do it says

> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown

I believe that I need to make some changes to the CMakeLists.txt in the package source directory, but have no idea how to do so.

I changed the minimum required from VERSION 2.8.9 to VERSION 2.8.12, maybe it has to something with it?

The code is very long so I just added the first 27 lines if need it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(Avogadro) # the name of your project

# The Avogadro version number, currently used by the Avogadro library too
set(Avogadro_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(Avogadro_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(Avogadro_VERSION_PATCH 0)
set(Avogadro_VERSION "${Avogadro_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Avogadro_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(Avogadro_VERSION_FULL "${Avogadro_VERSION}.${Avogadro_VERSION_PATCH}")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${Avogadro_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)

# this is adapted from KDE's FindKDE4Internal.cmake : default the build type to
# "release with debug info".
#
# We will define two other build types: Debug and Release.
# These names are case-insensitive i.e. you can do -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
endif()
message(STATUS "The build type is ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
include(MacroEnsureVersion)
include(TestIfWeNeedFPermissive)
```

Any suggestions of what can I do?

Comment: To compile with `cmake` you need a C or C++ compiler to be installed. On Linux, a common C++ compiler is `g++`. We could provide details on how to install `g++` or another Linux C++ compiler, but first we need to know which Linux distribution you are running. Are you running Ubuntu, given that you include "ubuntu" as a tag?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the assumption you are running Ubuntu, as you do not explicitly specify which Linux distribution you are running. I am assuming Ubuntu, since you have that as a tag.

CMake requires a working C or C++ compiler to compile code. The output you provided is telling you that CMake failed to find a C or C++ compiler installed on your computer.

Several compilers are available for Linux. A popular C++ compiler is `g++`.

`g++`, `gcc`, and `make` can be installed on Ubuntu using `apt` by running the following two commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I assume the Avogadro you are trying to install is [this program](https://github.com/cryos/avogadro). Please note that the [installation instructions](https://github.com/cryos/avogadro/blob/master/INSTALL) specify the tools required to build and install from the source code. You will need CMake (which you appear to already have installed), a working C++ compiler, GNU make, and the other two tools specified. Please install all build tools before you try to build Avogadro.